# MicroSoft Fakes on static with different returns

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I'm trying to unit test an object that uses a generic static factory class.  I'm not really at liberty to write out the factory.

I have to use Microsoft Fakes to shim it. (I think)  Never used it before.  My question is that it is a generic factory method used three times and needs to return 3 different sets of results.  Mock has the ability to seqence a method and return different results each time. Does Fakes have this ability?

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<T> Build<T>(IObjectA objA, IObjectB objB) where T : class
```

Inside the object it calls this method 3 times with different interfaces

```
IEnumerable<Base1> list = Factory.Build<Base1>(objA, objB);
IEnumerable<Interface1> list= Factory.Build<Interface1>(objA, objB);
IEnumerable<Interface2> list= Factory.Build<Interface2>(objA, objB);
```

How would the test method look for something like that?

```
using(ShimsContext.Create()) {


Mock<Base1> mockObj1 = new Mock<Base1>();
                //manager.Setup(t=> t.)

Mock<Interface1> mockObj2= new Mock<Interface1>();
                //manager.Setup(t=> t.)

Fakes.ShimFactory.BuildOf1IObjectAIObjectB<Base1>((objA, objB) => new List<Base1>() { mockObj1.Object }.AsReadOnly());

Fakes.ShimFactory.BuildOf1IObjectAIObjectB<Interface1>((objA, objB) => new          
 List<Interface1>() { mockobj2.Object }.AsReadOnly());

//Uses factory method 3 times
MyObjectThatUsesTheFactory = new MyObjectThatUsesTheFactory();
//test
}
```

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was on track.  It returns different results as laid out above.  Just a matter of getting all the mocks correct.

Thanks